# Is there a solution for PowerPoint map animation

Tags: animation, dictionary, powerpoint

I want to realize a function in PowerPoint map animation. The animation can be realized by any technologies. But it must accept the data, either from excel or from other sources and the map changes when changing the data.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "map".  I have answered the question by addressing animated graphs.  But perhaps you mean something more specifically map-like, e.g. countries?

Comment: Yes, it's interactive map in ppt. But i want the map can receive data from excel or other sources. So the map will change depending on the data. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively straightforward to embed Flash or Shockwave objects in PowerPoint.  [Find out more](http://www.amarasoftware.com/tutorials/importpowerpoint.html).  There is a similar process for embedding Excel graphs: [check it out](http://www.internet4classrooms.com/excel_animate_chart.htm).

Of course, these kinds of whizzy effects rely on using the later versions of the Office product set.

**edit**

The slide deck on that site doesn't feature data-driven animation.  It is a set of static pages which use PowerPoint custom transistions to animate the map.

I think that is not what you are seeking.  You need something which builds an animated map from some data source.  That is not a PowerPoint or indeed an Excel feature.  You need a specialized tool.  Such things exist - for instance MapCreator - but I haven't used any of them and I can't recommend one.

Once you have your animated map object it is probably a cinch to import it into PowerPoint or whatever else you want to do.

Comment: Thanks APC. While it's not some chart in ppt, i don't know how to explain, but you can see the url: http://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/trends.html

Comment: @thanks APC, i think you know what i want now. But i hope the animated map will be changable depending on the inputed data, which means the animated map is not fixed. For example, i want to specify a date for changing the color of part of the map.